How to set up a convex concave procedure for the minimization of $abc$?
From this post, it seems that there are a lot of advantage of approximating nonconvex problem with the convex concave procedure. Out of curiosity, suppose that I have a simple problem that is
$\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{\min }&{abc}\\
{}&{a_1 \le a \le a_2}\\
{}&{b_1 \le b \le b_2}\\
{}&{c_1 \le c \le c_2}
\end{array}$
Here $a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2,c_1,c_2$ are some positive numbers
And I know that the following decomposition exist from high school math
$abc = \frac{{{{\left( {a - b - c} \right)}^3} + {{\left( {a + b + c} \right)}^3} - \left[ {{{\left( {a + b - c} \right)}^3} + {{\left( {a - b + c} \right)}^3}} \right]}}{{24}}$
Then how can I set up a convex concave procedure to solve this problem ?
Note that since $a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2,c_1,c_2$ are just some number it is not clear if the individual cubic terms are convex or are concave. This has give rise to some difficulty in determining which term to linearize for the convex concave procedure.
Would you kindly help me with this ?
Thank you for your enthusiasm !
P/S: I already know that this problem can be tackle through geometric programming but I just want to know how to tackle it using a convex concave procedure.
